# Should I capitalize a word at the beginning of a sentence with a slash?

Tags: grammar, sentence, capitalization, sentence-starts, slash

Sorry about the badly written title. Basically, I have this sentence:

```
Clicking/Tapping on the icons brings up the DNA selection menu.
```

Should tapping be capitalized in this situation?

Comment: It's tempting to say that, as / stands for 'or' or 'and/or', ... However, the first rule of English is that English rarely behaves logically. The second is that where there's a grey area, grey people will pick a fight.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you are not supposed to capitalize a word after the slash until and unless both are proper nouns.Check this link out for more info:
http://www.really-learn-english.com/slash-punctuation.html check the 5th point.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to stress, the fact that either word could start the sentence or that either clicking or tapping gets you the menu.

The very fact that you didn't choose `or` suggests the former.

However,

> Clicking/tapping on the icons...

Is perfectly acceptable.  It simply suggests that your offering alternatives without ever explicitly using the word `or`.